# Set Priority Rules for aws alb ingress file

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have an ingress file for kubernetes , which is applied to aws alb . How to set priority for rules in ingress file ?

Code for ingress file that set priority in aws alb for rules.
Or
Automated priority setting.

For now we manually set priority in aws alb.